# Know Primary Key of Row after insert

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions

Is it possible to know the primary key of row you are about to insert, while inside a transaction? Let me give you an example:

```
START TRANSACTION;

INSERT INTO Donation 
    (Stuff1, Stuff2, Stuff3)
VALUES
    (1,2,3);
```

Now I want to know the primary key to this new row, while inside the transaction. Is it possible?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which DB system you are using. My SQL, oracle, db2 ...

Comment: The question is tagged with `mysql`

Comment: In that case: SHOW KEYS FROM tablename WHERE Key_name = 'PRIMARY' would work.

Comment: @JulienL, edit your answer to include that suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP then
Yes you can get primary key in PHP by 
 mysqli_insert_id();

```
 mysqli_query("INSERT INTO Donation (Stuff1, Stuff2, Stuff3) VALUES (1,2,3)");

// Print auto-generated id
echo "New record has id: " . mysqli_insert_id();
```